# Simple quiz not working in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a simple quiz to get the number of correct questions answered by a person when he submits the 'submit' button. But, it is always giving Zero. Pls help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
 var count = 0;
 if($('[name=q1]').val() == "Delhi"){count++;}
 if($('[name=q2]').val() == "Lotus"){count++;}
 alert(count);
});
});
```

```html
<body> 

<div> 
<p>Question: What is capital of India?</p>

<input type="radio" name="q1" value="delhi"> Delhi
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="mumbai"> Mumbai
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="kolkata"> Kolkata
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="lucknow"> Lucknow
</div>

<div> 
<p>Question: What is the national flower of India?</p>

<input type="radio" name="q2" value="rose"> Rose
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="lotus"> Lotus
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="sunflower"> Sunflower
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="tulip"> Tulip
</div>

<button>submit</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

> It is always giving '0', but if I select 'Delhi' and 'Lotus' it should give answer as **2**.

Comment: You have entered in the "value" the answer in lowercase but control it made with the first reading in upper case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1. `$('[name=q1]').val()` will give you the value of the *first* element with `name="q1"`, not the *checked* element. For that, add `:checked`.
2. You're comparing `"delhi"` with `"Delhi"`; case matters.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var count = 0;
    if ($('[name=q1]:checked').val() == "delhi") {
      count++;
    }
    if ($('[name=q2]:checked').val() == "lotus") {
      count++;
    }
    alert(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Question: What is capital of India?</p>

  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="delhi"> Delhi
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="mumbai"> Mumbai
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="kolkata"> Kolkata
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="lucknow"> Lucknow
</div>

<div>
  <p>Question: What is the national flower of India?</p>

  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="rose"> Rose
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="lotus"> Lotus
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="sunflower"> Sunflower
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="tulip"> Tulip
</div>

<button>submit</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your Js code, and you have to select the checked inputs, your code selects just the first input

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
     var count = 0;
     if($('input[name=q1]:checked').val() == "delhi"){count++;}
     if($('input[name=q2]:checked').val() == "lotus"){count++;}
     alert(count);
    });
});
```

```html
<body> 

    <div> 
        <p>Question: What is capital of India?</p>

        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="delhi"> Delhi
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="mumbai"> Mumbai
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="kolkata"> Kolkata
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="lucknow"> Lucknow
    </div>

    <div> 
        <p>Question: What is the national flower of India?</p>

        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="rose"> Rose
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="lotus"> Lotus
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="sunflower"> Sunflower
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="tulip"> Tulip
    </div>

    <button>submit</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">                        </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
 var count = 0;
if($('[name=q1]:checked').val() == "delhi"){count++;}
if($('[name=q2]:checked').val() == "lotus"){count++;}
 alert(count);
});
});
```

```html
<body> 

<div> 
<p>Question: What is capital of India?</p>

<input type="radio" name="q1" value="delhi"> Delhi
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="mumbai"> Mumbai
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="kolkata"> Kolkata
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="lucknow"> Lucknow
</div>

<div> 
<p>Question: What is the national flower of India?</p>

<input type="radio" name="q2" value="rose"> Rose
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="lotus"> Lotus
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="sunflower"> Sunflower
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="tulip"> Tulip
</div>

<button>submit</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: You need to look for the values of radio button that is been checked by the user. And do check the case sensitivity of your code

Comment: Please add description explaining the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename you values with a capital letter (lotus=>Lotus, etc).